# Expl3: Constructing command sequences from macro arguments

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3

In my `LaTeX` laboratory I am doing weird experiments with `expl3` (just started to use it some days ago, so regarding `l3` I am complete newbie)

I am trying to generate command sequence within of another macro, the name being based on macro argument(s) of the outer macro.

In `LaTeX(2e)` this is easy

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo#1\endcsname{Hello World}
}
```

and `\foo{bar}` would define `\foobar` (being not really useful here, of course)

I tried to apply this way (replacing `\expandafter` with `\exp_after:wN`) to a `expl3` command sequence with `\cs_new:Nn` and it works, but I want to know:

> Is there a better, cleaner way to get this in `expl3`, without using
>   `\csname` etc., just from the signature or using variants?

P.S. I am aware, that `expl3` commands are not really meant for typesetting, the output of `Hello World` is just an example.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Module named foo ;-)

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{%
  \exp_after:wN\cs_new:Nn  \csname foo_#1:\endcsname {Hello\space World}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foocall}{}{%
  \foo{start} % define \foo_start:
  \foo_start: 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\foocall
\end{document}
```

A not really similar question about the expansion is [Generalizing macros with LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122823/generalizing-macros-with-latex3), so I don't think my question is a duplicate.

Comment: `\cs_new:cn { foo_#1: } { Hello ~ world }`. Or may be in this case `\tl_set:cn { l_foo_#1_tl } { Hello ~ world }`.

Comment: @Manuel: Ah, `\cs_new:cn {foo_#1:}`... I was failing using the `:cn` signature, because I omit the `{...}` pair around `foo_#1:` ...

Comment: @Manuel: What's the advantage of using it as a token list with `\tl_set:cn`?

Comment: Remember that we are in TeX, so `\whatever foo_#1:` will take `f` as the first argument of `\whatever`. Well, the advantage of setting it as a token list is that it can contain `#` for instance, but, in any case, what matters is that if it *is* a token list you should set it as a token list, and `Hello ~  world`  looks like a token list to me :)

Comment: @Manuel: Yes, I see, but the `\foo_#1:` is only a very simplified example. There is more internal setup actually and there is basically more work to do internally, as well as `\foo_#1` would have some more arguments.

Comment: Okey, I meant in this case that you showed. By the way, you don't need `%` at all inside `\ExplSyntax(On|Off)`.

Comment: @Manuel: Thanks, I will think of removing `%` in future.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you're using `\exp_after:wN` you're most likely using expl3 the wrong way. :) Almost always expl3 has more elegant (and more readable) ways of doing things...

Comment: @clemens: That's why I posted this question ;-) Thanks

Comment: Oh. Then I misunderstood your question, sorry... The variants are a very powerful idea. The main idea is to define functions with `N` and `n` type arguments only and create the needed variants thereof later

Comment: @clemens: I've suspected the variants already (see my question in the pink quote block), but as I said already too: I am right at the start of using `l3`, so it's like a new language to me ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Du you know this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95175/

Comment: See also http://seanallred.com/latex3/2015/06/14/expl3-vs-l3.html :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: Seen now, thanks. I will rename the question. I actually meant `expl3` of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition mangling should probably be really constrained to the programming (expl3) layer with just the top level "latex2e" interface defined via xparse `\NewDocumentCommand`, also it is clearer in l3 if you define the commands first taking a normal `\zzzz` argument then the `\expandafter\...\csname` idiom is pre-packaged as "define a `c` variant" so...

```
\documentclass{article}

% Module named foo ;-)

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn\foo:N#1{\show#1\cs_new:Npn#1{Hello ~ World}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn\foo:N{c}


\NewDocumentCommand{\foocall}{}{%
  \foo:c{foo_start:} % define \foo_start:
  \foo_start: 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\foocall
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspected that the `variants` would be a cleaner way. Of course I would use the `expl3` way only in package, not in the document directly.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes but I meant that you should use xparse less and expl3 more, in your example.

Comment: You mean because of `\NewDocumentCommand`? Well, that's true. Consider it as a remnant of another trial I had. And as `xparse` already loads `expl3`, I was too lazy to switch back ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The interface is already there, just use a `c` type argument instead of `N`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Module named foo ;-)

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{%
  \cs_new:cn {foo_#1:}{Hello ~ World}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foocall}{}{%
  \foo{start} % define \foo_start:
  \foo_start: 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\foocall
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know that you mentioned expl3 in the title of your post. But we have the TeX primitive language for such things 30 years.

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\foo#1{\sdef{foo#1}{Hello World}}
\def\foocall{\foo{start}\foostart}

\foocall
```

Why to reinvent the wheel? Why to learn and use a new more complicated language?

Comment: I already mentioned the `\csname ...\endcsname` way in my question, I am using it for years already (ok, not 30 years ;-)) But thanks anyway. I am trying to learn the new and the 'old' TeX languages, because I like learning!